# How to analyze the change of native memory allocation

Tags: android, memory

I use Android DDMS's native heap tool to analyze the memory allocation of native code. This tool is very useful.

However, I'd like know newly created native memory when I do something on my phone. It seems that `DDMS` does not have this functionality. I heard that java's memory tool can compare 2 hprof file to get the change. Is there similar tool which can be used for native code?